# Rails 3 routing based on context

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, contextpath

I am trying to implement a "context" system similar to the one used by GitHub. For example, a Post may be created belonging either to the User or one of the Companies the User belongs to depending on whether to User is in the "User" context or a context that refers to one of the Companies.

As a part of this, I'd like to be able to do routing based on the user's current context. For example, if the User is in their own context, `/dashboard` should route to `users/show`, but if they are in the context for Company with ID 35, then `/dashboard` should route to `companies/35/dashboard`.

I could route `/dashboard` to a special controller responsible for making such decisions, such as `context#dashboard` which could then do a `redirect_to`, but this doesn't feel quite right (perhaps because we're taking logic that the Rails routing module should be responsible for and moving it to a controller?)

What would be the proper way to solve this problem in Rails 3?

Comment: I understand that you don't feel right with the dashboard controller as a pseudo router option, but having the router reading a context/session model from info passed by cookies/params seems weird too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem that I like. This will use the URLs from my original question.

First, assume a session-stored `Context` object that stores whether the user is in a "user" context or a "company" context. If the user is in a "company" context, then the ID of the company they're working as is in the object as well. We can get the context via a helper named `get_context` and we can get the currently logged-in user via `current_user`.

Now, we set up our routes as so:

`config/routes.rb`:

```
MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  get "dashboard" => "redirect", :user => "/users/show", :company => "/companies/:id/dashboard"
end
```

Now, `app/controllers/redirect_controller.rb`:

```
class RedirectController < ApplicationController
  def method_missing(method, *args)
    user_url    = params[:user]
    company_url = params[:company]
    context     = get_context

    case context.type
    when :user
      redirect_to user_url.gsub(":id", current_user.id.to_s)
    when :company
      redirect_to company_url.gsub(":id", context.id.to_s)
    end
  end
end
```

It's easy enough to keep the actual URLs for the redirect where they belong (in the `routes.rb` file!) and that data is passed in to a DRY controller. I can even pass in the ID of the current context object in the route.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems like the best way to me. Anything else would be more cluttered and not very standard.

Comment: Seems like this should be a comment.