# Making custom navigation depending on user role

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 type of users, 3 roles. With devise, I can get role with current_user.role method.

What is the cleanest way to make 3 different navigations (render some partial or whole layout) based on user's role?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to different controllers and/or actions based on role, you may be interested in this question and answer: [Rails 3 routing based on context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799818/rails-3-routing-based-on-context).

Answer (score 0):

I do this on this way:

```
<% if current_user.role? :admin %>
  <li class="apanel"><%= link_to_unless_current("Administracioni panel", :controller => 'admin', :action => 'index') %></li>
<% end %>
```

It is a little stupid way, but works :)